# Change string in file through whole git history, filter-branch is not rewriting the file

Tags: git, sed, git-filter-branch

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "sed -i 's/old/new/g' src/foo/bar.js &> /dev/null"
```

bfg repo cleaner didn't help either and it is unclear how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BFG repo cleaner helped me, I misunderstood replace text command. It turns out it takes file with data to remove as first argument